# Vue Showdown Default Classes

Tags: javascript, vue.js, markdown, showdown

I want to achieve the following say i the MD as

```
md:'#H1'
```

I want to render it as

```
<h1>H1</h1>
```

I was able to achieve this using [VueShowdown](https://vue-showdown.js.org/)

but I want add default class to every h1 tag like

```
<h1 class="custom">H1</h1>
```

I got something similar to this [here](https://github.com/showdownjs/showdown/wiki/Add-default-classes-for-each-HTML-element).

But I don't know how to use this in Vue.

Is it even possible in VueShowdown?

Is there any better library which has this functionality?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a simple directive:

```
Vue.directive('default-classes', (parentElement) {
  const els = parentElement.querySelectorAll('h1')

  els.forEach((el) => {
    el.classList.add('custom')
  })
  
})
```

Then apply that directive to the `VueShowdown` component:

```
<VueShowdown v-default-classes :markdown="markdownBinding" />
```

Comment: One more question on how does this works. Like after showdown creates the html tag it will then scan the code and add the classes and then rerender it?

Comment: @SameerGangar Yes, that's exactly how it works!